# Spell Check All of the Same Word In Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spell-checking

I am working on a program written by someone else and in their method headers a word is spelled wrong, repeatedly. When I hover over the word I get options to add the word to the dictionary, Change to '...', and more. However, I don't get an option to replace all instances of the word misspelled at once. Is there a way to achieve this in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

May be replace all ? (using ctrl + F or Ctrl + H)

but it could be dangerous and have side effects...
be sure to have some tests in place !

Or Replace/Find using Ctrl+F. it helps you to jump to the next occurence of the word, so you can check before replacing.